# Android Basics - Different class files

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have different class files in my application. I have 5 classes out of which 2 are activities and 1 is a service running. The other 2 are just classes. What is the lifetime of the variables in these 2 classes. I know that an activity can be killed by the OS , so i wont be able to use the variables of the activities in the service when the activity is killed. Can I use the variables in the other 2 class files anytime during the lifetime of the application, which are neither activities nor services?

Answer (score 2):

you can use those variable, if u make variables as static then value changes made in the activity or services, will persist. otherwise u can create object of those class variables in activity or service class(if u want separate instance of variable per activity or service).

Comment: Yes i want to have 1 variable for both activity and service. So ill make it static. So if service makes any change to this variable, when the activity comes back to life it will read this variable..

Answer (score 1):

If you have some objects that you would like to reference throughout the lifetime of the application I would recommend you store them in the application context. You can get a reference to the application context via one of the following methods:

[Context#getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)

[Activity#getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29)

In the manifest you define the custom Application class you want to use:check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm)

Then just create the object(s) you want in the onCreate method of the Application and provide getter(s) for other Android components to use.

Comment: Thank you.
What is the advantage of using this over using static variables from classes which are neither activities nor services?

Answer (score 0):

```
The other 2 are just classes. What is the lifetime of the variables in these 2 classes.
```

it depends on whether the variables are static of instance variable

if static : it will get in roll when the class loaded fist time.

if instance : it will depend on where you created the instance of that claas and what is the scope of that instance

```
so i wont be able to use the variables of the activities in the service when the activity is killed.
```

yes when the activity is killed that variable's of activity also get cleared.

```
Can I use the variables in the other 2 class files anytime during the lifetime of the application, which are neither activities nor services?
```

You can use lifetime of the application by

```
  1- make them static 

  2- or if they are not static declare them in application file of you project.
```

Comment: I can set the lifetime of the variable in the other 2 classes. Basically I want to use some variables in the service. Right now i am using them from the activity, so service crashes when activity no longer exists. So what should i make the variables in the other 2 classes so that i can use them in the service always? It will be a static variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! Ill make them static and i guess i should be able to use these variables in the service, even when the OS kills all the activities.

Answer (score 0):

The classes are there as long as another class or activity or service keeps a reference to it. If your activity has a reference to a class, then the class goes away when the activity is destroyed. Same for service. Unfortunately, there's no way in Android to pass the reference to a pojo (a "normal class" as you call it) from one activity to another, so you can't keep the classes alive easily.

I use RoboGuice, and by making your pojo's Injectable Roboguice classes, you can reference the same objects from activities and services, and if they're singletons, they remain alive as long as your app is running.

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps a reference to it." if i keep accessing a variable of a pojo through a service, that class will not be killed right..

Comment: suppose your activity has a field that contains your class. Like your class is A, and your activity has A a = new A(); then as long as the activity keeps this referene to a, the object a will remain. If your activity gets destroyed, the field a is destroyed also, and the corresponding object gets garbage collected. Or, if your object is in a list, as long as the list is there, your object is there. If you have a reference to your pojo in the Service, than the pojo will remain. You could setup your aidl or service calls in a way that the service can pass a reference to the pojo to an activity.

Comment: But as I said, I use RoboGuice wich makes life so much easier.